# Why is writing my own MiddleWare crashing my Django application?

Tags: django, django-middleware

I want to run a function before any view in my app is loaded, so I wrote my own middleware. It is in a file called "DoBeforeMiddleWare.py" located in the folder "my_app_name" and, for now, looks like

```
class DoBeforeMiddleWare:
    def process_request(self, request):
        return None
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        return None
```

I try to place this function in my list of middleware in settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'my_project_name.my_app_name.DoBeforeMiddleWare',
)
```

However, my app never loads after I restart passenger. Why? My app loads if I comment out the last line of |MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES|.

Answer (score 1):

`process_request` and `process_view` must return `None` or an `HttpResponse` object ([reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/?from=olddocs#writing-your-own-middleware)). If you want a no-op middleware, you should change them to return None, as follows:

```
class DoBeforeMiddleWare:
    def process_request(self, request):
        return None
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs)
        return None
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks but changing `class DoBeforeMiddleWare(request):` to `class DoBeforeMiddleWare(object):` is still stalling my application.

Comment: Revised my answer to include another issue with your class

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question (above), but I think the app is still stalling.

Comment: Updated my answer again :) You need to return None from process_request and process_view.

Comment: Thanks, but the updated version above strangely doesn't work either :( Is it because I'm accessing the middleware incorrectly?

Comment: Hmm. You might try removing my_project_name from the import. I always just use the app name. Can't think of much else though